# Populate UL with JSON

Tags: jquery, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to populate a UL list in a bootstrap dropdown menu with JSON.  Here is the bootstrap menu:

```
<section class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Select A State
<span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
</ul>
</section>
```

Here is the JSON:

```
//Create json list of dropdown
var jsonList = {"List" : [
    {"id" : "al", "Name" : "AL"},
    {"id" : "ak", "Name" : "AK"},
    {"id" : "az", "Name" : "AZ"}
]}

//Populate dropdown menu for selection of dropdown
$(document).ready(function(){
    var listItems = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonList.List.length; i++){
        listItems += "<li><a href='#'>" + jsonList.List[i].id + "'>" + jsonList.List[i].Name + "</a></li>";
    }
    $("#dropdown-menu").append(listItems);
});
```

I don't know if I am not setting my references right, or if I am not using correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a malformed anchor tag:

`listItems += "<li><a href='url/to/" + jsonList.List[i].id + "'>" + jsonList.List[i].Name + "</a></li>";` (removed double closing angled bracket)

Also the dropdown selector was a class selector

`$(".dropdown-menu").html(listItems);`

Comment: update href='url/to/' to reflect actual URL
working jsfiddle demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/normangr7/5s7rt0u9/

Comment: Works great.  I lost the ability to show what has been selected in the dropdown menu though.  https://jsfiddle.net/5s7rt0u9/2/

Comment: atm, you are creating an unordered list (UL).  You cant select these.  Please change the tagging according to the select list convention: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: ahhh.. now I see what you were trying to do :) gj

Comment: Thank you now this may be a bit complex but I need to get the value of the item when it is selected and post it to a PHP page.  Would I want to give the <li> a value and a name or the <a>?

Comment: I think that value is a deprecated attribute for li.  I would instead use a custom data-value attribute. (ref: http://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/).  Is there a reason for not using a select list though?  options by default have value attributes.

Comment: I was not sure if it could be done with the options attribute